# How to get uploaded file name?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I'm trying to make upload with Jersey multipart. Everything working well. But I cannot get uploaded filename. I think it's library problem.

Here is dependencies from my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My UpploadFileService

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file1") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

If I change `@FormDataParam("file1")` to `@FormDataParam("file")` POST request will return `Bad Request`. But it's working well without it.

How can I get filename? And why `@FormDataParam("file")` makes service return Bad Request?

#### UPDATE

My html for uploading

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/Project/api/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
  </p>

  <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Application

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(UploadFileService.class);
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the uploaded file name using    `String fileName = fileDetail.getFileName();`

`Jersey 1` uses `com.sun` package and `Jersey 2` uses `org.glassfish` package. Never mix them.  Replace your

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId> 
    <version>1.18.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

With this one:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
    <version>2.22.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: My html works well. Error appears when I use `file`, not `file1`. Read my question again please. I'm ready to answer your questions about it. I've added html to my question body.

Comment: oops..i missed that.. Can you   post the logs and also controller code?

Comment: I've added Application class. Which logs do you need?

Comment: The jetty logs generated,  when you hit the url  with code `@FormDataParam("file")`

Comment: Nothing appears in console and in log file when I do POST request with "file". Maybe there is available other logger that I don't know?

Comment: Ok. I believe jersey is thorwing your 400 bad request error. Try to print something to the console in your controller class. Implement exception handling and figure out where the error occurs from the stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96564/discussion-between-leqada-and-localhost999).